# SSLHandshakeException cannot authenticate user

Tags: java, jboss, ssl-certificate, keystore, sslhandshakeexception

I get this error while launching the application.

```
 org.jboss.mq.SpyJMSException: Cannot authenticate user; - nested throwable: (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)
org.jboss.mq.SpyJMSException: Cannot authenticate user; - nested throwable: (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)
```

I set my certificate path by `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "Path to certificate)`..

But this is not working me..Also I have imported the certificate to the "cacerts" of Java Home. But still I am getting the error..

Any help would be appericiated...

Answer (score 0):

The application authenticating the user has a Java keystore as its trust store. The trust store has to contain (as a trusted certificate) the certificate authority that signed the user's certificate. Put the certificate authority in a base-64 ca.cer file and use `keytool -import -keystore YourKeystore -alias ca -file ca.cer -trustcacerts`.